# Sum in terms of $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to write the sum

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{2k-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ in terms of $e^x$? That is, using the fact that $$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: $2^{2k-1}\cdot x^k = \frac{1}{2} (4x)^k$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2^{2k-1}x^k = \dfrac{(4x)^k}{2}$. Thus your sum is $\dfrac{e^{4x}}{2}$